# Radio buttons doesn't show up when I use setSingleChoiceItems of AlertDialog.Builder with listadapter

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, listadapter

Radio buttons doesn't show up when I use setSingleChoiceItems of AlertDialog.Builder with listadapter. Radio buttons show up if i use Charsequence[] array. Please take a look at the code I am using. Thanks in Advance!!

public class ExampleApp extends Activity {

```
Context mContext;
ListAdapter myListAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mContext = this;
    myListAdapter = new myListAdapter(mContext);
    AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alt_bld.setTitle("Select any icon");
    alt_bld.setSingleChoiceItems(myListAdapter, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected icon = "+imageName[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
    alert.show();
}

private class myListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    public myListAdapter(Context mContext){
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return imageName.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder myViewHolder;
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.listadapterview, null);
            myViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            myViewHolder.txt_icon_name = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CheckedTextView01);

            convertView.setTag(myViewHolder);
        }
        else{
            myViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        myViewHolder.txt_icon_name.setText(imageName[position]);
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        CheckedTextView txt_icon_name;
    }
}

String[] imageName = {"icon1", "icon2", "icon3"};
```

}
//XML for listadapter view

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem. Even though I was using `CheckedTextView` the radio button was not showing up.

The solution was to add the following to the `CheckedTextView` element in the layout file:

`android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"`

Here's my "dialog_list_item.xml" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_list_item_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" 
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    >
</CheckedTextView>
```

Here's the code to create the list adapter:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
     this.getContext(), R.layout.dialog_list_item, 
     cursor, 
     new String[]{"title"}, 
     new int[]{R.id.dialog_list_item_title}
);
```

I googled the hell out of it to come up with an answer, but I eventually found the answer right in the sdk:

```
$android_sdk_home/platforms/android-x.x/data/res/layout/simple_list_item_single_choice.xml
```

Sometimes the source code is better than any google search. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, `R.layout.listadapterview` is not a `CheckedTextView`, which is what is needed for `singleChoice` to work.

Comment: Hi, I changed the code as per your suggestion but now nothing comes up in alert dialog box. This is what code looks like now. I have also attached the xml which I am using for the listadapter view.

Comment: Please find above the edited code. I have changed TextView to CheckedTextView but now nothing is showing up. In the available documentation on developer.android.com it is said that the setSingleChoice will provide a radio button for the listadapter also. Don't know what am I missing.